# Control order of execution of parallel.foreach tasks

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

I have a list of table names (student, exam, school).

I use a `Parallel.ForEach` loop to iterate over the table names and do processing for each table, with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8`.

My problem is that my `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't always engage in work stealing. For example, when two tables are left to process, they may be processed one after another instead of in parallel. I'm trying to improve performance and increase throughput.

I tried to do this by creating a custom `TaskScheduler`, however, for my implementation I need a sorted list of tasks with the easiest tasks ordered first, so that they aren't held-up by longer-running tables.  I can't seem to do this by sorting the list passed to `Parallel.ForEach` (`List< string >`) because the tasks are Enqueued by the `TaskScheduler` out-of-order. Therefore, I need a way to sort a list of tasks inside my CustomTaskScheduler, which is based on https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/a-custom-taskscheduler-in-c/

How can I control the order in which tasks are passed by the `Parallel.ForEach` to the `TaskScheduler` to be enqueued?

Comment: Why not use List of Tasks and WaitAll?

Comment: @SandrisB I'm not familiar, but a quick Google tells me it's for asynchronous programming - I need to make the tasks execute in parallel, how is that possible with WaitAll?

Comment: Showing your code would be ideal here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method employs two different partitioning strategies depending on the type of the source. If the source is an array or a `List`, it is partitioned statically (upfront). If the source is an *honest-to-goodness*¹ `IEnumerable`, it is partitioned dynamically (on the go). The dynamic partitioning has the desirable behavior of work-stealing, but has more overhead. In your case the overhead is not important, because the granularity of your workload is very low.

To ensure that the partitioning is dynamic, the easiest way is to wrap your source with the [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) method:

```
string[] tableNames;
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(tableNames), tableName =>
{
    // Process table
});
```

¹ (The expression is borrowed from a comment in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Parallel.cs.html#ecf3d8a35545d82b))

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very insightful and helpful, on initial inspection it's worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking up [partitioners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl). Managing threads on a Parallel loop has some overhead, so there is some built-in logic to try to keep this overhead small while still balancing the work across all cores propperly. This is done by dividing the list into chunks and adjusting the chunk-size to hit some sweet-spot.

I would guess that ordering the tasks as as smallest first will work against the paritioners balancing. I would try ordering the work largest first if balancing is the goal. Another thing I would try is to partition the work items with some constant chunk-size and see if that helps. Or perhaps even write your own partitioner.

I'm not sure it is a great idea to try to enforce some execution order. Since you do not control the OS scheduler there cannot be any guaranteed ordering. And even if you can make it more ordered, it would probably be at the cost of throughput.

Also, if you are spending lots of time optimizing the parallelization, are you sure the rest of the code is optimized?